# IE11 sets navigator.cookieEnabled to false if F12 Dev Tools are open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

Whenever I open a page in IE, cookies are enabled as normal. however, as soon as I open the dev console and reload the very same page, `navigator.cookieEnabled` returns false. I actually can write and read cookies, though. however, my script relies on the possibility to detect if cookies are enabled. I already tried a few things regarding cookie settings in ie, but all of them seem to only affect the browser if the devtools aren't open.

I thought about writing a small function that creates a cookie, reads it and then deletes it immediately, making sure cookies are written, but that's only a last resort.

Why does IE set `navigator.cookieEnabled` to false as soon as I open F12 developer tools?